# What is the best user-input or user-signup form that you have come across?

Tags: forms, gui-design

In particular, what have you seen that makes it very simple and fluid as a user to input lots of manual information?  Maybe with automatic suggestions, nice design, and minimalistic?

Thanks!

Comment: As written this question is far too broad and completely opinion based. What is the usability concept or concern you are trying to address here?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "input lots of manual information" forms are one use case I can think of below points:

- The best way is to allow users to input in stages.
- Set logical categories instead of lengthy monotonous forms
- Reduce the manual input and add options sets like checkbox, dropdowns, radio
- Have a progress bar to indicate the remaining inputs
- Have defaults
- Highlight the mandatory sections as the inputs are in progress instead of throwing an error on submit.
- Grouping mandatory sections
- keep users informed:  sharing personal info will not be spammed by systems

Also have very subtle colors and layout and components should be very device specific because often web forms used in mobile can get painful and annoying.